# How do I track only the last value for a user in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, mixpanel

Here's the scenario:

- Clients come into my product and enter their employment income.
- They can adjust that income any time through the edit mode.
- If a client entered $50K during onboarding, then changed it to $100K later, I only want GA to "keep" the $100K value. When a pull a report to find out what the average value of employment income is for users of my site, I only want the $100K reflected for that client, not the average of $75K.

How can I do this in GA? In Mixpanel, for instance, there are certain types of "people properties" available for this scenario.

Thank you all in advance!

This product is for Angular JS...

Comment: _"If a client entered $50K during onboarding"_ do you save that in a database as part of the client information? _"then changed it to $100K later"_ — how _much_ later? Days or weeks later in a different session?  This sounds to me like you are trying to get GA to do analysis that you should be doing on your dataset itself, not on the metadata about your site usage.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics you would use a session scopes custom variable. "Session scope" means exactly what you want, only the last value per session is kept.

You need to create the dimension in the property settings and select the proper scope (you have a choice between hit scope, user scope and session scope - you want the latter) and then "set" in your tracking code. Since dimensions are transmitted with an interaction hit you need to set them before the pageview (or event tracking) call. You address the dimensions not with the name, but with the numeric index of their creation.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('set', 'dimension1', '<value>');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

You can then access the dimension by the name you gave in the interface either by setting them as secondary dimension in a custom report, or using it in a custom report.

This retains the value for a user via a session. You can also choose a user scoped custom dimension which will only keep the last value for a user with multiple sessions. But user scope relies on cookies (unless you use the "user id" feature where you set an unique key per user from the serverside), so it might not always work for you.